# NumPy efficiency in dataset preprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, data-preprocessing

I am currently working on a research project relating to the use of neural networks operating on EEG datasets. I am using the BCICIV 2a dataset, which consists of a series of files containing trial data from subjects. Each file contains a set of 25 channels and a very long ~600000 time step array of signals. I have been working on writing code to preprocess this data into something I can pass into the neural network, but have run into some efficiency issues. Currently, I have written code that determines the location in the array of all the trials in a file, then attempts to extract a 3D NumPy array that is stored in another array. When I attempt to run this code however, it is ridiculously slow. I am not very familiar with NumPy, the majority of my experience at this point being in C. My intention had been to write the results of the preprocessing to a separate file that can be loaded to avoid the preprocessing. From a C perspective, all that would be necessary is to move the pointers around to format the data appropriately, so I am not sure why NumPy is so slow. Any suggestions would be very helpful since currently for 1 file it takes ~2 minutes to extract 1 trial, with 288 trials in a file and 9 files, this would take much longer than I would like. I am not very comfortable with my knowledge of how to make good use of NumPy's efficiency improvements over generic lists. Thanks!

```
import glob, os
import numpy as np
import mne

DURATION = 313
XDIM = 7
YDIM = 6
IGNORE = ('EOG-left', 'EOG-central', 'EOG-right')

def getIndex(raw, tagIndex):
    return int(raw.annotations[tagIndex]['onset']*250)

def isEvent(raw, tagIndex, events):
    for event in events:
        if (raw.annotations[tagIndex]['description'] == event):
            return True
    return False

def getSlice1D(raw, channel, dur, index):
    if (type(channel) == int):
        channel = raw.ch_names[channel]
    return raw[channel][0][0][index:index+dur]

def getSliceFull(raw, dur, index):
    trial = np.zeros((XDIM, YDIM, dur))
    for channel in raw.ch_names:
        if not channel in IGNORE:
            x, y = convertIndices(channel)
            trial[x][y] = getSlice1D(raw, channel, dur, index)
    return trial

def convertIndices(channel):
    xDict = {'EEG-Fz':3, 'EEG-0':1, 'EEG-1':2, 'EEG-2':3, 'EEG-3':4, 'EEG-4':5, 'EEG-5':0, 'EEG-C3':1, 'EEG-6':2, 'EEG-Cz':3, 'EEG-7':4, 'EEG-C4':5, 'EEG-8':6, 'EEG-9':1, 'EEG-10':2, 'EEG-11':3, 'EEG-12':4, 'EEG-13':5, 'EEG-14':2, 'EEG-Pz':3, 'EEG-15':4, 'EEG-16':3}
    yDict = {'EEG-Fz':0, 'EEG-0':1, 'EEG-1':1, 'EEG-2':1, 'EEG-3':1, 'EEG-4':1, 'EEG-5':2, 'EEG-C3':2, 'EEG-6':2, 'EEG-Cz':2, 'EEG-7':2, 'EEG-C4':2, 'EEG-8':2, 'EEG-9':3, 'EEG-10':3, 'EEG-11':3, 'EEG-12':3, 'EEG-13':3, 'EEG-14':4, 'EEG-Pz':4, 'EEG-15':4, 'EEG-16':5}
    return xDict[channel], yDict[channel]

data_files = glob.glob('../datasets/BCICIV_2a_gdf/*.gdf')

try:
    raw = mne.io.read_raw_gdf(data_files[0], verbose='ERROR')
except IndexError:
    print("No data files found")

event_times = []

for i in range(len(raw.annotations)):
    if (isEvent(raw, i, ('769', '770', '771', '772'))):
        event_times.append(getIndex(raw, i))

data = np.empty((len(event_times), XDIM, YDIM, DURATION))

print(len(event_times))

for i, event in enumerate(event_times):
    data[i] = getSliceFull(raw, DURATION, event)
```

EDIT:
I wanted to come back and add some more details on the structure of the dataset. There is the 25x~600000 array that contains the data and a much shorter annotation object that includes event tags and relates those to times within the larger array. Specific events indicate a motor imagery cue which is the trial that my network is being trained on, I am attempting to extract a 3D slice which includes the relevant channels formatted appropriately with a temporal dimension, which is found to be 313 timesteps long. The annotations gives me the relevant timesteps to investigate. The results of the profiling recommended by Ian showed that the main compute time is located in the getSlice1D() function. Particularly where I index into the raw object. The code that is extracting the event times from the annotations is comparably negligible.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to find out where the slow parts are? If so it might be helpful to tell us

Comment: Doing so now, to simplify Im calling getSliceFull once for the first element of event_times, this should be able to extrapolate for further elements. Once i get the profiling finished Ill follow up, thanks by the way, wasnt aware that cProfile existed before now.

Comment: Thus far, I am able to note that each call of getSlice1D is taking 1.366 seconds, this is called 22 times during the process of getSliceFull, so this is the main source, apparently my ~2 min estimate was off, I believe the indexing on the return statement is most likely the source of the time issue, but will continue profiling.

Comment: The majority of the time seems to relate to read calls from various methods, based on my experience with NumPy, I believe that the indexing into the raw object is where the majority of time is taken, is there a better way to extract a piece of a NumPy array than I am doing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer bc the formatting in comments is kind of garbage but

```
def getIndex(raw, tagIndex):
    return int(raw.annotations[tagIndex]['onset']*250)


def isEvent(raw, tagIndex, events):
    for event in events:
        if (raw.annotations[tagIndex]['description'] == event):
            return True
    return False

for i in range(len(raw.annotations)):
    if (isEvent(raw, i, ('769', '770', '771', '772'))):
        event_times.append(getIndex(raw, i))
```

Notice how you're iterating over the I. What you could do is instead

```py
def isEvent(raw_annotations_desc, raw_annotations_onset, events):
    flag_container = []

    for event in events:    # Iterate through all the events
        # Do a vectorized comparison across all the indices
        flag_container.append(raw_annotations_desc == event)
    # At this point flag_container will be of shape (|events|, len(raw_annotations_desc) 

    """
    Assuming I understand correctly, for a given index if  
        ANY of the events is true, we return true and get the index, correct?
    def getIndex(raw, tagIndex):
        return int(raw.annotations[tagIndex]['onset']*250)
    """
    flag_container = np.asarray(flag_container)  # Change raw list to np array
    
    # Python treats False as 0 and True as 1. So, we sum over the cols 
    # and we now have an array of shape (1, len(raw_annotations))
    flag_container = flag_container.sum(1)  

    # Add indices because we will use these later
    flag_container = np.asarray(np.arange(len(raw_annotations)), flag_container)

    # Almost there. Now, flag_container has 2 cols: the index AND the number of True in a given row
    
    # Gets us all the indices where the sum was greater than 1 (aka one positive)
    
    flag_container = flag_container[flag_container[1,:] > 0]  

    # Now, an array of shape (2, x <= len(raw_annotations_desc))
    flag_container = flag_container[0, :]  # We only care about the indices, not the actual count of positives now so we slice out the 0th-col

    return int(raw_annotations_onset[flag_container] * 250)
```

Something to that effect :) That should speed things up a bit

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into implementing some of these changes, however I do not believe that this will resolve my compute time issue, as I believe that the main compute timesink is found in the getSlice1D() function, I added a more thorough description of the dataset at the end of the original question in the edit.